# WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 307

Tags: python, websocket, signalr

I am trying to connect to a SignalR hub from python client using "signalr-client-0.0.7".In connection.start() its giving "WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 307".The hub hosted in a remote machine , am using the IP of the server to connect to the hub.

```
***Please find the callstack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\signalrClient.py", line 16, in <module>
    connection.start()
  File "D:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\signalr_client-0.0.7-py3.5.egg\signalr\
_connection.py", line 50, in start
  File "D:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\signalr_client-0.0.7-py3.5.egg\signalr\
transports\_auto_transport.py", line 28, in start
  File "D:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\signalr_client-0.0.7-py3.5.egg\signalr\
transports\_ws_transport.py", line 38, in start
  File "D:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\websocket_client-0.40.0-py3.5.egg\webso
cket\_core.py", line 487, in create_connection
    websock.connect(url, **options)
  File "D:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\websocket_client-0.40.0-py3.5.egg\webso
cket\_core.py", line 214, in connect
    self.handshake_response = handshake(self.sock, *addrs, **options)
  File "D:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\websocket_client-0.40.0-py3.5.egg\webso
cket\_handshake.py", line 65, in handshake
    status, resp = _get_resp_headers(sock)
  File "D:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\websocket_client-0.40.0-py3.5.egg\webso
cket\_handshake.py", line 122, in _get_resp_headers
    raise WebSocketBadStatusException("Handshake status %d", status)
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 307***
```

Am not able to find out why this error is hppening and what this 307 status code corresponds to?
Could anyone faced the same issue ?
Please share your insights on the issue.

Thanks in advance 
Susmitha

Comment: Hi all, Any idea about this issue??